# Powershell doesn't work like I want it to

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

My problem with this powershell script is that I want to get table content from number 3 table:

[image]

Number 3 table has a different URL ending than the first two and problem with my script is that, no matter what I do, I can't get information from the third one. I have tried by ID name and all that but nothing seems to work. If I change the URL it will still get info From the first and second, and if I let it run so that maybe it can pull something from third one but it always stops at the end of a second one. For the ending line I only want to communicate with the third table. I want something like this↓

[image]

```
$Uri = "https://etherscan.io/address/0xcd895fc1c9e24c5c5ce3fb692593c402bbfb53c7#tokentxns"

$InfoPage = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri $Uri

$InfoPage.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("tbody") | ForEach-Object {

    $Headers = $null

    $_.getElementsByTagName("tr") | ForEach-Object {
        $OutputRow = $_.getElementsByTagName("td") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InnerText
        $OutputRow[6].Trim()
        $OutputRow[4].Trim()
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont understant what you want ...? do you want to trap the value displayed in the datatable when the third  Erc20 is selected? and you havent problem when the first or second is selected?

Comment: i only wanna communicate with the erc20 tab and it's datatable on the webpage. Yes i have no problem getting info from the firsrt 2... but have no way to get info from the third one... added a new pic as well, what info i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have looked at the html page and you have an iframe for this table and the id of this iframe is `tokenpageiframe`

```
$Uri = "https://etherscan.io/address/0xcd895fc1c9e24c5c5ce3fb692593c402bbfb53c7#tokentxns"
$InfoPage = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri $Uri

$iframe = $InfoPage.ParsedHtml.getElementById('tokenpageiframe');

$iframe.document.getElementsByTagName("tbody") | ForEach-Object {

    $Headers = $null

    $_.getElementsByTagName("tr") | ForEach-Object {
        $OutputRow = $_.getElementsByTagName("td") | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InnerText
        $OutputRow[6].Trim()
        $OutputRow[4].Trim()
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn... i love how smart you people are here... anyways thanks alot... and thank you for your time